# Is there a better way to scrape this data?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For work, I was asked to create a spreadsheet of the names and addresses of all allopathic medical schools in the United States. Being new to python, I thought that this would be the perfect situation to try web scraping. While I eventually wrote a program that returned the data I needed, I know that there is a better way to do it as there were some extraneous characters (eg: ", ], [) that I had to go into excel and manually remove. I would just like to know if there was a better way I could have written this code so I can get what I needed, minus the extraneous characters.

Edit: I have also attached an image of the csv file that was created to show the extraneous characters that I'm speaking about.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv  

link = "https://members.aamc.org/eweb/DynamicPage.aspx?site=AAMC&webcode=AAMCOrgSearchResult&orgtype=Medical%20School" # noqa
# link to the site we want to scrape from

page_response = requests.get(link)
# fetching the content using the requests library

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.text, "html.parser")
# Calling BeautifulSoup in order to parse our document

data = []
# Empty list for the first scrape. We only get one column with many rows. 
# We still have the line break tags here </br>
for tr in soup.find_all('tr', {'valign': 'top'}):
    values = [td.get_text('</b>', strip=True) for td in tr.find_all('td')]
    data.append(values)

data2 = []
# New list that we'll use to have name on index i, address on index i+1
for i in data:
    test = list(str(i).split('</b>'))
    # Using the line breaks to our advantage. 
    name = test[0].strip("['")
    '''Here we are saying that the name of the school is the first element
       before the first line break'''

    addy = test[1:]
    # The address is what comes after this first line break
    data2.append(name)
    data2.append(addy)
    # Append the name of the school and address to our new list.

school_name = data2[::2]
# Making a new list that consists of the school name
school_address = data2[1::2]
# Another list that consists of the school's address.

with open("Medschooltest.csv", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as toWrite:
    writer = csv.writer(toWrite)
    writer.writerows(zip(school_name, school_address))
    '''Zip the two together making a 2 column table with the schools name and
       it's address'''

print("CSV Completed!")
```

[Created CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEzUe.png)

Comment: The best solution when structuring data, is to not need the data, the next best solution is to start with structured data. If neither of these are feasible then consider throwing out context by normalizing the tokens aka filtering out anything not in `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]`, although this is too broad of a question in general, do you have a specific question about how to filter the extraneous characters? Or a more specific question that wouldn't be primarily based on opinion? The "E" in ETL, especially from the web is a messy deal.

Answer (score 1):

It seems applying conditional statements along with string manipulation can do the trick. I think the following script will lead you real close to what you want.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

link = "https://members.aamc.org/eweb/DynamicPage.aspx?site=AAMC&webcode=AAMCOrgSearchResult&orgtype=Medical%20School" # noqa

res = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

with open("membersInfo.csv","w",newline="") as infile:
    writer = csv.writer(infile)
    writer.writerow(["Name","Address"])

    for tr in soup.find_all('table', class_='bodyTXT'):
        items = ', '.join([item.string for item in tr.select_one('td') if item.string!="\n" and item.string!=None])
        name = items.split(",")[0].strip()
        address = items.split(name)[1].strip(",")
        writer.writerow([name,address])
```

Comment: Edited to use `.strip()` in the end of this line `name = items.split(",")[0].strip()` so that all the names are visible accordingly in the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have knowledge of SQL AND the data is in such a structured manner, it would be the best solution to extract it to a database.